# Why Java's Optional doesn't call Consumer in ifPresent()?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type, consumer

```
public class TestSupplier {

Optional<Integer> opt1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    TestSupplier ts1 = new TestSupplier();

    ts1.opt1 = ts1.average(100,20,30,80);
    Consumer<Integer> cns1 = (x) -> x += 3;
    ts1.opt1.ifPresent(cns1);
    System.out.println(ts1.opt1.get());

}


private Optional<Integer> average(int... n1) {
    if (n1.length == 0) return Optional.empty();
    int sum = 0;
    for(int score: n1) sum += score; 
    return Optional.of(sum/n1.length);

}

}
```

when I run the code the result is 57 (that is the correct result of 100, 20, 30, 80 average) but I create a Consumer that should increment the result by 3... but it seems to not work.

Can someone help me?

Comment: "`(x) -> x += 3`" What variable do you think you're incrementing there?

Comment: `n1` is a local variable, so why should `cns1` affect its state?

Comment: What you wanted to do is `ts1.opt1.map(x -> x + 3).get()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Consumer` action is actually being run but the body you provided modifies only a local instance which eventually gets lost. The `ifPresent()` method should be used for performing side-effects(actions) only.

If you want to perform a calculation on a value held by an `Optional` instance, use `map()` instead.

```
ts1.opt1
  .map(x -> x + 3).orElseThrow(...)
```

Remember to be careful when using `get()` on an `Optional` instance. Before you decide to use it, have a look at `orElse`, `orElseGet`, and `orElseThrow`.

Comment: The method is named `orElseThrow`. Regarding `get()`, you can also say that `orElseThrow` “essentially transforms `NullPointerException` into a” `WhatEverYouWantException`. So you have to write `orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new)` to get rid of a “deprecated” warning in the future. It’s a good thing that I always used `orElseThrow(NullPointerException::new)` anyway…

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the wrong function name. If you want NPEs, just stop using Optionals.

Comment: That just was a bit of sarcasm, but anyway, the choice of using `Optional` or not is not always yours, i.e. the Stream API methods return `Optional`s, while equivalent Collection API operations throw `NoSuchElementException` in a similar situation, e.g. `Collections.max(list, cmp)` has the same behavior as `list.stream().maxBy(cmp).get()`. I’m not convinced that deprecating `get()` is so useful.

Comment: Note that `Optional.get` won't be deprecated in Java 9, but the advice to be careful using it is good.

Comment: @StuartMarks thanks for the clarification :) I remember that I read this http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2016-April/040484.html. I will update my answer now

Answer (score 1):

```
Consumer<Integer> cns1 = new Consumer<Integer>() {
    public @Override void accept(Integer x) {
        // x is a local variable
        x += 3; // unboxing, adding, boxing 
        // the local variable has been changed
    }
};
```

It is that case when turning a lambda into an anonymous class perfectly makes this all clear to understand.

The best possible way here is

```
ts1.opt1.map(x -> x + 3).ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

You could use an instance of a mutable class (e.g. the `AtomicInteger` class):

```
Consumer<AtomicInteger> cns1 = x -> x.addAndGet(3);
```

which changes its state after accepting the `Consumer<AtomicInteger>` (although it is not recommended, look at [@pivovarit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2229438/pivovarit)'s answer).

Furthermore, the line

```
IntStream.of(100, 20, 30, 80).average().ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

might replace all your routine work.